# How to execute commands from my python script via html button using ajax?

Tags: python, ajax

Im creating a web application botnet for my finale year dissertation project, which can only be done via local networks due to ethical reasons. My webpage can execute the python script to start it up, but im having issues stopping it. I have been told to use ajax to perform a POST request, but i have never touched ajax before. Is it possible using ajax to search my script and look for an "exit" command and allow me to click a button to stop the server from running?

python script command

```
elif command == "exit":
                target.close()
                target.remove(target)
                ips.remove(ip)
                break
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/threaded.py",
    type: "POST",
    data: array(
        command: 'exit'
    ),
    success: function(response){
        // Do something to let the user know if it worked
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you start your python script? Do you use any framework?

Comment: i use shell_exec( python url) to start the program and i do not use frameworks